# With tigerVNC 1.10.90, tigerVNC cannot send the client's first clipboard event to the target device when accessed over RDP

Tags: web, rdp, vnc

Use THE H5 access and RDP protocol to access Windows devices, and use tigerVNC-1.10.90 to control and send clipboard data. When the clipboard data is sent for the first time, the clipboard data is not sent successfully. VNC has received the clipboard, but the clipboard is not sent to the target device.Data synchronization on the client clipboard is normal.